# My JLabel refresh differently, depending on the Eclipse project. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, timer, jlabel

Yesterday, I post a question because I had some troubles to refresh the text displayed in a JLabel. Many people answered quickly (and I thank them very much) and correct my code. But, after the modifications, I had the same problem.

This morning, I made a new try : I copied my class and pasted it in another Eclipse project : same machine, same Eclipse, just another project with other libraries, unused in that test code. Result : no problem, it works perfectly. I also tried to delete all the libraries in the first project, thinking it would be the problem. But, without the external jars, I still have the problem. I also tried to create a "new JAVA project" in Eclipse with just my simple code but the problem appears too. My question is : why and how to correct this artefact ?

Here is the code I' using :

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestLabel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
JLabel label;
static int i=0;
static Timer timer;
TestLabel() {
    label = new JLabel("0");
    this.add(label);
    timer=new Timer(100, this);
    //timer.setInitialDelay(10);
    timer.start();      
}

public static void createJFrame () {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Test");
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new TestLabel());
    frame.setVisible(true);     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createJFrame();
        }
    }); 
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    i+=1;
    label.setText(String.valueOf(i));       
}
}
```

The problem in the code in the first project is : the JLabel don't change at each modification of "i". It display something like : 1, 2, 3 (...)42, 47, 52, 57...

PS : another question about the use of Stackoverflow. When I correct a code but still have problems, shall I create and "answer" with the corrections made and the new problems or opening a new question ? I always have some doubts about that.

Thank you for all your answers. Regards.

Comment: Different Java version maybe? I know I had problems with things refreshing in one particular Java update, though I don't remember which one. (And not just in my code; it broke a lot of other programs too)

Comment: you might want to call `label.repaint()` after changing the text of it.

Comment: Well... I made a new try. The difference between the project was the JRE used : version 1.7 or 1.8. With the version 1.7 : it's ok. With the 1.8, I have some troubles. I know how to correct my problem but I still can't answer to the "why"...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It was a problem with the JRE version. With version 1.7, it's ok. With 1.8, I have a bug. So, I'll keep the 1.7.